# How to populate map of string and pair of vectors of double

Tags: c++, vector

What is the best way to populate with values this type?

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::pair<std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>>> buf;
```

So, I need something like this:

```
(“Label”, {1,2,3}, {100,200,300})
```

Thank you in advance!

**UP:**
So, I came to this. But it looks not very nice I think:

```
double a[] = {0.1, 0.2};
double b[] = {0.0, 0.0};
foo.insert( make_pair("box", make_pair(vector<double>(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])), vector<double>(b, b + sizeof(b) / sizeof(b[0]))) ) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's C++11 or newer

`buf x = {{"Label", {{1,2,3}, {100, 200, 300}}};`

**EDIT**

Without C++11 if you really want to populate with literals (like in your example), create helper function:

```
template <int N, int M>
std::pair<std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>> build_pair(double(&x)[N], double(&y)[M])
{
    return std::make_pair(std::vector<double>(x, x + N), std::vector<double>(y, y + M));
}
```

and you can use it:

```
    double x[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    double y[] = { 100, 200, 300 };
    b["Label"] = build_pair(x, y);
```

Comment: can you use boost lib? (see: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html it emulates some C++11 features)

Comment: and no boost as well. it's painfull for me.

Comment: so you're left with standard `push_back`, `insert`and `make_pair` :(
you might be able to simplify a little using array to vector constructor

Comment: yeah. I think this is the only way. So what is construction should be then?

Comment: I've added helper function, see if that's enough for you to make it cleaner :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `insert`

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::pair<std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>>> buf;

int main()
{
    buf foo;
    foo.insert({"Label", {{1,2,3}, {100,200,300}}});
}
```

Note that you need an enclosing `{}` to indicate your `std::pair`.

Comment: i got syntax error in VS 2010 on : missing ')' before '{'

Answer (score 1):

With lots and lots of braces:

```
buf my_map {         // <== whole map
    {                // <== next individual map item
        "Label",     // <== key
        {            // <== value
            {1.0, 2.0, 3.0},       // <== value.first
            {100.0, 200.0, 300.0}  // <== value.second
        } 
    }  
};
```

Which when you put the whole item on one line reads:

```
buf my_map {
    {"Label", {{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, {100.0, 200.0, 300.0}}}  
};
```

Comment: sorry, syntax error in VS2010 on this construction.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you meant that the vectors already exist and you're not initializing the map at the time of construction with literal values, then you'd typically use [`std::make_pair`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/make_pair/) for creating the pair of vectors, as well as the key/value pair going into the map.

```
#include <utility>

buf my_map;
my_map.insert(std::make_pair(label, std::make_pair(vector1, vector2)));
```

Comment: no, no vectors at the beginning. everything is from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::pair<std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>>> buf;

buf mybuf {
    {
        "Label",
        {
            {1,2,3}, {100,200,300}
        }
    },

    {
        "Label2",
        {
            {4,5,6}, {400,500,600}
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm not surprised. Get a real compiler kiddo.

Comment: i have limitations on this. of course, i would rather do it smart way

Comment: the notation above is c++11. For older compilers you'll need to add items individually as per the other answers :(

Answer (score 0):

For simplifying the creation of a (with compile-time constants) filled map I created templates like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <type_traits>
template<typename... Ts>
constexpr auto make_map(Ts&&... ts)
    -> std::map<typename std::common_type_t<Ts...>::first_type,typename std::common_type_t<Ts...>::second_type>
{
    return { std::forward<Ts>(ts)... };
}//---------------------------------------------------------
```

It can be used like this:

```
using namespace std;
auto myDict = make_map(make_pair(666,string("the number of the beast"))
                      ,make_pair(667,string("the neighbor of the beast"))
                      );
```

creating myDict as a "map< int,string >".

Or in your case use it like this:

```
using namespace std;
auto myDict = make_map(make_pair(string("label")
                                , make_pair(make_vector(1.,2.,3.)
                                           ,make_vector(100.,200.,300.)
                                           )
                                )
                      );
```

("make_vector" can be defined pretty similar to "make_map")

The make_... approach is helpful (or at least "to me seems to be") because it omits an explicit template type declaration by taking the type(s) from the parameters.

Maybe this is somehow helpful to others too (or at least inspiring :-))...